# What weapons would be most effective for a military in space?

Tags: space, weapons

In the future FTL travel is discovered and human beings now travel all across the galaxy. All interstellar travel and trade is governed by the UEF ( United Earth federation). To make sure all people are following the laws they have put in place such as no trading illegal substances and no interfering with alien societies, they have formed a military unit which travels across the galaxy and upholds the laws. My question is which weapons would be best for fighting against criminals in outer space?

To make everything clear here are the guidelines for what there weapons should do?

• They should not kill the person they are used on( non- lethal)
• They should be able to pierce armour and metal from spaceships 
• They should be able to operate  normally in space
So which weapons would be best in space energy weapons like lasers, traditional ballistic weapons like guns on earth, or electric like tasers
•They should be cheap enough to manufacture millions of them
•They should be multipurpose tools/weapons

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect us to answer this question. Think of the similar question "What weapon would be most effective for a 21st century military?" there is no singular answer to this question. The answer is dependent upon a bunch of context including but not limited to, expected defenses, cost, logistics requirements, existing infrastructure, manufacturing ability, intended use case. There is no military ever that only had one weapon. There is little chance that this will change in the future.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at all the other space weaponry questions around here, and then narrow your question down considerably.

Comment: Wrote about Roentgen laser and then read _non-lethal_. Deleted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no good answer.

- Space is a lethal environment. Even a notionally non-lethal weapon can kill people when the people on the bridge of a starship are incapacitated.
- Weapons that can penetrate the hull of a starship can probably penetrate the body of a crewmember, too. Most likely with lethal effects. That applies to lasers, guns, missiles, etc.

Many science fiction settings have either stun guns, or weapons to disrupt technological systems without harming people, like the [ion cannon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ion_cannon) from Star Wars or the effectors from Iain Banks' Culture stories. But those are *quite* fictional.

If you copy the technobabble from somewhere, make sure that you're not so close that you infringe on copyrights ...

Answer (score 0):

Since FTL travel is possible,

[Teleporting](http://www.popularmechanics.com/science/news/a27271/chinese-scientists-successfully-teleported-a-particle-to-space/) handcuffs directly on criminals' wrists, using some [insulant harmless covering](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61U797%2BFrIL._SL1001_.jpg) material, to avoid close to 0 Kelvin contact with skin, may also be possible.